# Unable to read serialized file fingerprint. Unrecognized value found in the data stream

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run my code, this error message is displayed

this is the entire message on the output:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not read entry ':app:mergeDebugResources' from cache executionHistory.bin (D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Resque\.gradle\5.4.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.bin).
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.get(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:135)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache$1.create(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:47)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.readFile(DefaultFileLockManager.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$UnitOfWorkFileAccess.readFile(DefaultCacheAccess.java:404)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.get(DefaultMultiProcessSafePersistentIndexedCache.java:45)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$1.create(AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache.java:47)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$1.call(CacheAccessWorker.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker$2.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:184)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:223)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:204)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.flushOperations(CacheAccessWorker.java:174)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.CacheAccessWorker.run(CacheAccessWorker.java:144)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read serialized file fingerprint. Unrecognized value found in the data stream.
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.FingerprintMapSerializer.readFileType(FingerprintMapSerializer.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.FingerprintMapSerializer.readFingerprint(FingerprintMapSerializer.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.FingerprintMapSerializer.read(FingerprintMapSerializer.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.FileCollectionFingerprintSerializer.read(FileCollectionFingerprintSerializer.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.FileCollectionFingerprintSerializer.read(FileCollectionFingerprintSerializer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.DefaultPreviousExecutionStateSerializer.readFingerprints(DefaultPreviousExecutionStateSerializer.java:128)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.DefaultPreviousExecutionStateSerializer.read(DefaultPreviousExecutionStateSerializer.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.history.impl.DefaultPreviousExecutionStateSerializer.read(DefaultPreviousExecutionStateSerializer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache$DataBlock.getValue(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:675)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache.get(BTreePersistentIndexedCache.java:127)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

My PC went standby mode before finishing the apk build task. after waking up the PC, i got this error and all next build was ended up with the same error.

**How Solved?**

I just removed the `executionHistory.lock` and `executionHistory.bin` files at the mentioned address. For your case it is `D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Resque\.gradle\5.4.1\executionHistory\`.
removing just the lock file seems to solve the issue but i removed all just for sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for the execution History folder in your system or in the project folder you are working on
2. Make sure its the recently updated. (As there could be a number of folders, one for each project)
3. Delete the entire folder or delete the files executionHistory.bin and execution history.lock

That's it, clean and run!