# How to fix Unable to read serialised file fingerprint. Unrecognized value found in the data stream

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After my PC went off while I was building the project, I keep having this error **Unable to read serialized file fingerprint. Unrecognized value found in the data stream.**

When I checked the exception, I saw this

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not read entry ':app:mergeDebugResources' from cache executionHistory.bin (/Users/euniceb/my_project/location/.gradle/6.1.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.bin).
```

While trying to fix this, I saw this question [Unable to read serialized file fingerprint. Unrecognized value found in the data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348292/unable-to-read-serialized-file-fingerprint-unrecognized-value-found-in-the-data) and tried the solution, but it didn't work for me.

I've tried deleting my cache and .gradle file. I've changed the location of my android project but it still gives the same error.

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not read entry ... from cache taskArtifacts.bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431953/could-not-read-entry-from-cache-taskartifacts-bin)

Comment: No it doesn't. I've tried deleting it and it still returns the same error.

Comment: You deleted your entire .gradle directory (e.g. "c:\users\myuser\.gradle" for Windows), did an Android Studio build, and allowed A/S to re-create it.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, that was what I did

Comment: Q: Did you delete .gradle (and everything in it) under your global gradle  (e.g. "c:\users\myuser\.gradle" for Windows), or your project .gradle (e.g. c:\projects\myproject\.gradle)?  Or both?  Be sure to delete the *global* directory and, if that doesn't work, then the *project* directory.  Be sure to delete .gradle itself.  Post back what you find.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that and get back to you

Comment: It works now. Thank you. Can I mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Thank you for the followup, and glad you got it working :)